# Publish facebook with Python 3.8

Tags: python, facepy

I downloaded a script from Github that makes posts on facebook, I configured it with the Api token and the group id, but when I run it, a syntax error in line 41, appears and I'm not able to find out where the error is.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time
from facepy import GraphAPI

api = ""

graph = GraphAPI(api)

message = '''

Add all your contents to be posted to facebook groups here

'''


# Find the ids of your desired groups from http://lookup-id.com/  
# and add this in this array groups

groups = [ '273873207240416' ]


for group_id in groups:
    print "Posting to " + 'https://www.facebook.com/groups/' + str(group_id)
    graph.post(path =str(group_id) + '/feed', message=message)
    time.sleep(10)
print "Done"
```

[Source code link on Github](https://github.com/tshrinivasan/post-to-facebook-groups)

Comment: The code was updated a long time ago. He used python 2 at that time.

Comment: @QuanVO But isn't it possible to fix the code? OR to make it work, do I need to downgrade Python?

Comment: Can you change all `print x` to `print(x)` and test again?